# JSON data not populateing select menu

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get JSON data to fill my select menu. But it doesn't load the data in to my select menu. How can I make the JSOn to fill my < select > menu?

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="countries">Countries</label>
        <select class="form-control um_frm" id="countries"></select>
 </div>
```

jQ:

```
  $.getJSON('../php/country.php',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(index,item){
      var addedCountries ='<option value="'+item.country_id+'">'+item.country+'</option>';
    });
    $('#countries').html(addedCountries);
  });
```

JSON:

```
[
 {
  "country_id":"1","0":"1","country":"Afghanistan","1":"Afghanistan"},   
 {
  "country_id":"2","0":"2","country":"Albania","1":"Albania"
 }
]
```

Comment: you checked you are receiving the json right?

Comment: `addedCountries` is not within the scope of `$('#countries').html(addedCountries);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following JS:

```
$.getJSON('../php/country.php',function(data){
    var addedCountries = "";
    $.each(data,function(index,item){
        addedCountries += '<option value="'+item.country_id+'">'+item.country+'</option>';
    });
    $('#countries').html(addedCountries);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for you Problem:
For the future: Don't mix JS and HTML ;-)

```
$.each(data,function(index,item){
    $('<option/>', {
        value: item.country_id,
        text: item.country
    }).appendTo('#countries')
});
```

//edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/j3jjj5z6/

Comment: Sometimes it's a good idea to mix them, for performance reasons. If there is a lot of option nodes, it's much faster to insert them with one `.html()` call like Anne does than to insert them one at a time.